# Flink s3 write performance optimization

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-flink, amazon-eks

I am working on a flink application on kubernetes(eks) which consumes data from kafka and write it to s3.

We have around 120 million xml messages of size 4TB in kafka. Consuming from kafka is super fast.

There is a high back pressure while writing to s3. We are not even hitting the s3 PUT request limit which is arounf 3500 requests/sec. I am seeing only 300 writes per minute to S3 which is very slow.

I am using StreamFileSink to write to s3 with Rolling policy as OnCheckpointPolicy.

Using flink-s3-fs-hadoop-*.jar and s3:// as path (not using any s3a or s3p)

Other than this I dont have any config related to s3

```
    StreamingFileSink<Tuple3<String,String, String>> sink = StreamingFileSink
            .forRowFormat(new Path(s3://BUCKET),
                    (Tuple3<String,String, String> element, OutputStream stream) -> {
                        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(stream);
                        out.println(element.f2);
                    })
            // Determine component type for each record
            .withBucketAssigner(new CustomBucketAssigner())
            .withRollingPolicy(OnCheckpointRollingPolicy.build())
            .withBucketCheckInterval((TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)))
            .build();
```

Is there anything that we can optimize on s3 from streamfilesink or in flink-conf.xml ?

For checkpointing too I am using s3:// instead of s3p or s3a

```
env.setStateBackend((StateBackend) new RocksDBStateBackend(s3://checkpoint_bucket, true));
        env.enableCheckpointing(300000);
```

Comment: How do you have checkpointing configured? It's recommended to use flink-s3-fs-presto for checkpointing to S3, as the hadoop implementation is very slow for checkpointing to S3.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, thanks for the response. I have added the checkpoint related code to post. I am using s3 prefix for checkpointing but not s3p, would that change anything as checkpoint is not taking time ?

Comment: @DavidAnderson using presto over hadoop s3 library is still recommended with Flink 1.14 ?